# vim/vi/sed: Act on a certain number of lines from the end of the file

Tags: linux, bash, vim, sed, awk

Just as we can delete (or substitute, or yank, etc.) the 4th to 6th lines from the beginning of a file in vim:

```
:4,6d
```

I'd like to delete (or substitute, or yank, etc.) the 4th last to the 6th lines from the *end* of a file. It means, if the file has 15 lines, I'd do:

```
:10,12d
```

But one can't do this when they don't know how many lines are in the files -- and I'm going to use it on a batch of many files. How do I do this in vim and sed?

I did in fact look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046878/using-sed-to-match-a-pattern-and-deleting-from-the-line-to-the-end-of-the-file), but have not found it useful.

Answer (score 10):

Well, using `vim` you can try the following -- which goes quite intuitive, anyway:

```
:$-4,$-5d
```

Now, using `sed` I couldn't find an exact way to do it, but if you can use something other than `sed`, here goes a solution with `head` and `tail`:

```
head -n -4 file.txt && tail -2 file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. So how would I do a substitution using the head and tail, the way I usually do in sed and vim ?

Comment: `tail -6 file.txt| head -2 | sed -e '...'`
Note that the syntax for sed and vim s commands are a little different. You may be better off saving the file using `>` and then opening it with vim.

Answer (score 7):

In Vim, you can subtract the line numbers from `$`, which stands for the last line, e.g. this will work on the last 3 lines:

```
:$-2,$substitute/...
```

---

In sed, this is not so easy, because it works on the *stream* of characters, and cannot simply go back. You would have to store a number of last seen lines in the *hold space*, and at the end of the stream work on the hold space.
Here are some recipes from [sed1line.txt](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt):

```
# print the last 10 lines of a file (emulates "tail")
sed -e :a -e '$q;N;11,$D;ba'

# print the last 2 lines of a file (emulates "tail -2")
sed '$!N;$!D'

# delete the last 2 lines of a file
sed 'N;$!P;$!D;$d'

# delete the last 10 lines of a file
sed -e :a -e '$d;N;2,10ba' -e 'P;D'   # method 1
sed -n -e :a -e '1,10!{P;N;D;};N;ba'  # method 2
```

Answer (score 6):

From the 4th last to the 6th lines from the end of a file: use [`tac`](http://man.cx/tac) to reverse the file

```
tac filename | sed 4,6d | tac
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 passes with awk, first pass to count the number of lines and the second to print or delete whatever lines you like, e.g.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{numLines++;next} {fromEnd = numLines - FNR} fromEnd > 6 || fromEnd < 4' file file

awk 'NR==FNR{numLines++;next} {fromEnd = numLines - FNR} fromEnd < 6 && fromEnd > 4' file file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;${s/([^\n]*\n){3}//;q};N;7,$!ba;P;D' file
```

This works by making a moving window of 6 lines in the pattern space (PS) and then deleting the first three of them on encountering the last line.

- `:a` is a loop label
- `${s/([^\n]*\n){3}//;q}` delete the first three lines of the PS at end of file and quit.
- `N` append a newline and then the next line to the PS.
- `7,$!ba`' if *not* lines `7` to the `$` (end-of file) that is lines `1` to `6`, loop back to beginning i.e. label `:a`
- `P;D` for the line range `7` to `$` (end-of-file) print upto the first newline in the PS and then delete upto and including the first newline and begin a new cycle.

The second to last clause creates the window by default in that the lines `1` to `6` are appended into the PS. From line `7` to the end a line is added at the end and the first line is printed then deleted.

Alternatively:

```
sed -e ':a' -e '$s/\([^\n]*\n\)\{3\}//' -e '$q' -e 'N' -e '7,$!ba' -e 'P' -e 'D' file
```