# Sed doesn't replace a pattern that is understood by gedit

Tags: regex, sed

I need to delete some content that is followed by 5 hyphens (that are in separate line) from 1000 files. Basically it looks like this:

> SOME CONTENT
>   -----
>   SOME CONTENT TO BE DELETED WITH 5 HYPHENS ABOVE

I've tried to do that with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046878/using-sed-to-match-a-pattern-and-deleting-from-the-line-to-the-end-of-the-file) solution, but it didn't work for me:

- this command — `sed '/-----/,$ d' *.txt -i` — can't be used because some of these texts have lines with more than 5 hyphens;
- this command — `sed '/^-----$/,$ d' *.txt -i` — resulted in having all the files unchanged).

So I figured out that it might be something about "^" and "$" characters, but I am both sed and RegEx newbie, to be honest, and I don't know, what's the problem.

I've also found out that this RegEx — `^-{5}$(\s|\S)*$` — is good for capturing only these blocks which start exactly with 5 hyphens, but putting it into sed command gives no effect (both hyphens and text after them stay, where they were).

There's something I don't understand about sed probably, because when I use the above expression with gedit's *Find&Replace*, it works flawlessly. But I don't want to open, change and save 1000 files manually.

I am asking this question kinda again, because the given solution (the above link) didn't help me.

The first command I've posted (`sed /-----/,$ d' *.txt -i`) also resulted in deleting full content of some files, for instance a file that had 5 hyphens, new line with a single space (and no more text) at the bottom of it:

> SOME CONTENT
>   -----
>   single space

EDIT:

Yes, I forgot about `'` here, but in the Terminal I used these commands with it.

Yes, these files end with \n or \r. Is there a solution for it?

Comment: Please fix the commands you say you're running, `sed /-----/,$ d' *.txt -i` is an invalid command (unbalanced quote)

Comment: `^-----$` will not match if the file has DOS line endings, i.e. `\r\n` at the end of each line.

Comment: Yes, these files end with \n or \r. Is there a solution for it?

Comment: Ending with `\n` is not a problem, that's what sed expects. Ending with `\r\n` is a problem. You'll need to either change them to unix line endings (e.g. with `dos2unix` or use a regex that matches them e.g. `'/^-----\r\?$,$d'` and a `sed` that allows control characters (e.g. use the `-e` option to GNU sed)

Comment: There's no such thing as "a regexp". What works for gedit won't necessairly work for sed or awk or grep or any other command-line UNIX tool. Unfortunately you have to learn about the different regexp varieties (BRE, ERE, and PCRE), which tools use them, which tools have which options to enable different regexp versions, and which tools have additional features (e.g. word boundaries, capture groups and backreferences) and/or caveats (e.g. delimiters, lack of escape sequence expansion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
 sed '/^-\{5\}/,$ d' *.txt -i
```

Note that `{` and `}` need escaping.

Comment: As far as I can see, it worked (I've checked like 20 files) — except for 1 file. "----- + \n + single space" in that new line stayed, where they were. Still thank you. My problem was the "$" sing from Jonathan Wakely's answer.

Comment: I've noticed that your command deletes the content of many files where more than 5 hyphens are more than once in these files. That's why I needed "$" char to specify the only pattern that should be deleted, but apparently I cannot use it. I've tried to use something like this `sed '/^-\{5\}(?!-)/,$ d' *.txt -i`, but it had no efect at all.

Comment: idk what you think `(?!-)` might mean but it makes no sense in the context of your question in BRE syntax as used by sed, nor would it if you enabled EREs as you can with some seds. Maybe you're confusing sed with perl or some other tool that supports PCREs? I can't tell from your question what it is you're really trying to do or what the problems might be at all though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed  '/^-----/p;q' file
SOME CONTENT
```

or

```
$ sed -E '/^-{5}/p;q' file
SOME CONTENT
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to delete from `-----` on it's own line (which may end with \r) to the end of the file? That'd be:

```
awk '{print} /^-----\r?/{exit}' file
```

The above will work using all awks in all shells in all UNIX systems.